# What is the optimal blind algorithm for the game, 2048?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

The game [2048](http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/) has exploded in popularity since its release in February 2014.  For a description of the game and discussion of optimal algorithms, see [What is the optimal algorithm for the game 2048?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342854/what-is-the-optimal-algorithm-for-the-game-2048). Here is the [source code](https://github.com/gabrielecirulli/2048).

A **blind algorithm** for 2048 is one that cannot see the board;  the only feedback the algorithm receives is whether or not an attempted slide occurred (we may suppose a blocked slide produces an audible beep).  A blind algorithm is practically useful for getting started in 2048 without having to give the game your undivided attention.

Here is my **specific question**: is there a blind algorithm for 2048 that consistently does better than a mean score of 3500 in 10^6 trials? (only post an answer you have validated)

This is the performance of the LADDER algorithm, which may be notated as (LD* RD*)* (+U).  That is, one loops over "left, down repeatedly until stuck, right, down repeated until stuck" and presses up iff left, right, and down are all blocked, which occurs iff the top row(s) are completely empty and the bottom row(s) are completely full.  I call this algorithm LADDER because of the letters LDDR, and because I imagine climbing down ladders like Mario in Donkey Kong.  The motivation for the algorithm is to maintain an increasing gradient from top to bottom of the board, similar to many of the non-blind algorithms.

Here is a histogram for 10^6 trials of LADDER colored by top tile on the final board with bin width 32 and mean 3478.1.  I generated this data by simulating the game and algorithm in Python, using probability .9 that each new tile is a 2, as in the original game.  You can't see the 1024 games at this vertical scale but they are sparsely distributed between 8000 and 16000. The fractal structure relates to the number of occurrences of the top tile, second-from-top tile, and so on.  By comparison, random button mashing gave a mean of about 800 in 10^4 trials.

[image]

Comment: I don't see a specific question here. Possible answers will just be different strategies that people think are good, but that would not answer the question, since you ask for an *optimal* algorithm, so without a proof no answer fulfills that criterion. I think the same applies for the original question

Comment: I appreciate your point Niklas B, and rephrased the more specific question as "Is there a blind algorithm that consistently does better 3500 in 10^6 trials?".  I recognize this still falls short of proof, but I think it should still be reasonable to reach community consensus on a proposed better algorithm through simulation (which I expect is the best we can do here, though I'd love to be proven wrong).

Comment: I still feel your question is very unclear. First you ask about an *optimal* algorithm. Then you ask for an algorithm that does better than some specific other algorithm in randomly generated games for which you don't provide the generation framework. Then you say you want an algorithm does well for the start to mid-game, but your framework seems to measure the total score up to the end of the game. What this will turn out to be is a place where people propose different solutions and test them against each other. *Stack Overflow is not for competitions*.

Comment: Isn't the generation framework specified for 2048?

Comment: @NoahSnyder I have no idea, but I also can't be expected to figure that out myself. Questions on Stack Overflow are supposed to be self-contained and *minimal*.

Comment: This is my first time posting, I was inspired to do so by the original post on optimal algorithms for 2048 which I found extremely interesting, and so I modeled the title on that (and assumed my question would be as appropriate).  I've now modified my post to more directly refer there for a more complete description of the game, and clarified that I only meant that one should only start with a blind algorithm.  In practice, this is what most people do to save time, so it's meant as a practical question more than a competitive one (supposing that doing well in the game has value).

Comment: I understand that my question was underspecified as originally stated and have modified it to be far more specific. I specify a blind algorithm that that achieves 4.5-fold performance over random play, and ask whether there is a better one in a specific sense (consistently higher mean score in 10^6 trials). I now also ask that people only post algorithms that they have validated as meeting this criteria. This is more specific than the original 2048 question, and surely not a duplicate but rather of some practical value to those who want to play as humans but get off to a fast start.

Answer (score 2):

The most important in the 2048 game is to concentrate the high numbers along the borders and not in the middle. So a very good strategy is to put everything along the bottom as long as possible. Your LADDER algorithm does this, but I'd like to concentrate more on the left side and not switch to the right side completely. This is the algorithm in pseudo code:

```
while(true)
    {
    if (down)
        continue;
    elseif(left)
        continue;
    elseif (right)
        continue;
    else
        {
        up;
        down; //if forced to go up; go back down immediately
        }
    }
```

Using your convention this would be:

```
((D*L)*R)U
```

in words: go down as long as you can; if you cannot; go left; if you cannot go left; go right. You will rarely need to go up.

Since I won't have time shortly to implement this to use it 10⁶ times; I hope someone else can give the correct statisctics for this, but my guess is this will outperform your LADDER algorithm

Comment: You can be forced to go up (if every row is completely full).  In such a situation the obvious strategy is up followed immediately by down.

Comment: Since the question has been put on hold, I've modified it to be more precise.  As such, please validate that your algorithm meets the specified criteria, which will require implementing it and running it 1000000 times.

Comment: @Noah Snyder: you are right: going up will be last resort...

Comment: @JonathanBloom I'd love to start implementing the whole thing to start validating and playing around, but I don't have the time for that. So please either validate my algorithm or give me a link where I can find your code...