# Expectimax Algorithm for 2048 Not Performing Expectation as Intended?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, game-engine

I wrote an Expectimax solver for 2048 using the heuristics noted on the top ranking SO post "[Optimal AI for 2048](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342854/what-is-the-optimal-algorithm-for-the-game-2048/22498940#22498940)".

However, my expectimax algorithm performs maximization correctly but when it hits the expectation loop where it should be simulating all of the possible tile spawns for a move (90% 2, 10% 4) - it does not seem to function as intended.

```
game2048.prototype.ai = function (theState, depth, playerOne, alpha) {
    var state = this.clone(theState); 
    var moves = this.validMoves(state);

if (moves.length == 0) { // avoid game losing states
    return Number.MIN_VALUE;
}
if (depth == 0) { // base case.
    return this.utility(state);
}

if (playerOne) {
    for (var i = 0; i < moves.length; i++) {
        state.move(moves[i]); // check child state
        var temp = this.ai(state, depth - 1, false, alpha); // find the maximum utility for depth given
        if (alpha > temp) {
            break; // prune the children that we won't choose.
        } 
        alpha = Math.max(temp, alpha);
        state.reset();
    }
    return alpha;
} else { // perform expectation 
    var avg = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < moves.length; i++) {
        state.addRandomTile();
        state.move(moves[i]);
        avg += this.ai(state, depth - 1, true, alpha);
        state.reset();
    } return avg / moves.length;
}
}
```

Any ideas on how I could be incorporating expectation incorrectly into this algorithm?

It SHOULD somehow be calculating all possible tile spawns and returning score of an average of all the simulated spawns.

Comment: Without you showing `addRandomTile()`, in particular, or describing your intentions and observations?

Comment: addRandomTile() just adds a single tile of value 4 or 2 (90%  2, 10% 4) to an open spot on the game board. My goal is to calculate the value of the game board at every simulated tile spawn and return the average.