# How to applied alpha-beta pruning in implementing 2048 AI agent with minimax algorithm?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning, pruning, 2048

I'm developing an AI for 2048, and am about to apply minimax algorithm.

However, the search tree of 2048 is actually like a Expectiminimax tree without Min role. I wonder if I don't have Min role, how could I apply alpha-beta pruning in practice?

If I shouldn't apply alpha-beta pruning in this scenario, how could I reduce the useless search branch?

Any thoughts would be appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the alpha-beta algorithm is not suitable for this game.
Please check this answer how you could implement a heuristic: [What is the optimal algorithm for the game 2048?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342854/what-is-the-optimal-algorithm-for-the-game-2048)