# Seeking the Ultimate Strategy: Conquering 2048's Challenge

Tags: algorithm

Immersed in 2048, I crafted an algorithm to merge tiles, aiming to minimize 2 and 4-tiles. Yet, my approach only nets 4000 points, far from the 20,000 max. Is there a better strategy?

Diving into 2048, I meticulously honed an algorithm, focused on merging tiles to reduce the presence of 2 and 4-tiles. My expectation was a higher score, but alas, I'm stuck at 4000 points. What did I miss?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you missed if you don't provide any code. In any case if you're looking for a better strategy check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342854/what-is-the-optimal-algorithm-for-the-game-2048